# Can't access Frame analysis window in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, directx-11

I am trying to debug a Wpf application which is using DirectX 11 for rendering.

i've been having some [rendering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171158/rendered-texture-is-transparent-in-directx-11), hence was going to use graphics debugger.

Now, i do not see any option to select frame analysis[see pic 1 below].

Also the capturing of the frame doesn't actually finish it keeps going.[see pic 2 below].

I am using VS2015 Enterprise on Windows 7, .NetFramework 4.5 and above.

PIC 1
[image]

PIC 2
[image]

Now what do i require to enable get the pixel history or frame analysis window for graphics debugging and have my frame capture to finish.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the feedback. So sorry about you can't access the frame analysis feature. It's by design. The frame analysis feature only support on Windows Blue and Windows 10 at present. It's not support on Windows 7. Please upgrade your OS, then capture frames and have a try.

Sincerely,
The Visual Studio Graphics Team

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Cloud Wu I have even tried on my Windows 10 PC but had no luck and my problem still persists.